# Real eigenvalues of a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

Suppose the rotation matrix 
$$\pmatrix{ \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta}$$
has real eigenvalues. Then what would the value of $\theta$ be?

I know that the eigenvalues of this matrix are $\{e^{\pm i\theta}\}$. To derive the condition under which the eigenvalues are real, I found the characteristic function and set the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ $>0$. From this, I got $\sin^{2}\theta <0$. Since sine is a square term, how can it be negative?!  Am I right?

Comment: $\ge 0$. Set $\theta=0$ and you get the identity matrix, which has real eigenvalues. And what about $\theta=\pi$?

Comment: Think geometrically (as well): rotations over which angle(s) map vectors to scalar multiples of those vectors? Since rotations don't change the magnitude of the vectors: this is mapping to itself or to its opposite...!

Comment: So, any integral multiple of $π$, will make value of sine, 0 and thereby the eigen values real. Right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using the characteristic equation seems like a crutch - better to think about what it all *means*, in my opinion.

Say that matrix is $A_\theta$ and $x$ is an eigenvector. Then $x\ne0$ and $A_\theta x=\lambda x$. This says that rotating $x$ through an angle $\theta$ results in a vector parallel to $x$ (where I'm taking $y$ and $-y$ to be "parallel".) That's clearly impossible unless $\theta $ is $0$ or $\pi$ mod $2\pi$. (Which says in turn that $A_\theta=\pm  I$, so $\lambda=\pm1$.)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with your approach is that the eigenvalues can be real if the discriminant is zero, too.  $\sin^2 \theta < 0$ has no solution, but $\sin^2 \theta = 0$ gives $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi$.  The first gives you the identity matrix, the second its opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Using Euler's formula, the eigenvalues,  $e^{\pm i\theta}$ will be real iff $\sin\theta=0$.  Thus $\theta=k\pi\,,k\in \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
\cos\left(\theta\right) & \sin\left(\theta\right) \\
-\sin\left(\theta\right) & \cos\left(\theta\right)
\end{array}\right]
$$
is given by
$$
\chi_A(t)
= \left\lvert\begin{array}{rr}
t - \cos\left(\theta\right) & -\sin\left(\theta\right) \\
\sin\left(\theta\right) & t - \cos\left(\theta\right)
\end{array}\right\rvert
= t^{2} - 2 \, \cos\left(\theta\right) t + 1
$$
To ensure that this polynomial has real roots, we need 
$$
(-2\,\cos(\theta))^2-4\cdot(1)\cdot(1)\geq0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\cos^2(\theta)\geq 1
$$
Of course, this is only possible if $\cos(\theta)=\pm1$. Thus our desired values of $\theta$ are $\theta=k\cdot\pi$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.